# ModalContentLayout is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onChildStartedNativeGesture(p0: View!, p1: MotionEvent!)

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, react-native-navigation

```
> Task :react-native-navigation:compileReactNative63ReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/user/Documents/app/node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/src/reactNative63/java/com/reactnativenavigation/react/modal/ModalContentLayout.kt: (12, 1): Class 'ModalContentLayout' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onChildStartedNativeGesture(p0: View!, p1: MotionEvent!): Unit defined in com.facebook.react.uimanager.RootView
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-navigation:compileReactNative63ReleaseKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

I think this is a minor kotlin issue happening in the library anyone can help?

Function causing the issue

```
    override fun onChildStartedNativeGesture(androidEvent: MotionEvent?) {
        mJSTouchDispatcher.onChildStartedNativeGesture(androidEvent, this.getEventDispatcher())
    }
```

I don't know kotlin so I need help of someone who know